# Installing Clang+LLVM 3.4 from llvm.org into Saucy 13.10

Tags: apt, clang

I'm trying to setup Saucy to install clang and llvm 3.4 from the official LLVM apt repo, but it doesn't work. I only get the 3.4 snapshots from Ubuntu's own repos. I followed the instructions from http://llvm.org/apt/ and added the following to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://llvm.org/apt/saucy/ llvm-toolchain-saucy main
deb-src http://llvm.org/apt/saucy/ llvm-toolchain-saucy main
```

But after doing an `sudo apt-get update`, I still only see the packages from the Ubuntu repo:

```
$ sudo apt-get --print-uris download clang-3.4
'http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/llvm-toolchain-snapshot/clang-3.4_3.4~svn183914-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb' clang-3.4_3.4~svn183914-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb 11996652 sha256:5b5f10b0d90d0654672dca596980616814a5e3eca4346f43011d2e914602bbe5
```

Is this a problem on my end, or is the `llvm.org` apt repo broken?

Comment: Use `apt-cache policy clang-3.4`.

Answer (score 4):

Seems the instructions might be incorrect. I added the following to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://llvm.org/apt/saucy/ llvm-toolchain-saucy-3.4-binaries main
deb-src http://llvm.org/apt/saucy/ llvm-toolchain-saucy-3.4-binaries main
```

Note `llvm-toolchain-saucy-3.4-binaries`.

Seems to work so far:

```
$ sudo apt-get --print-uris download clang-3.4
'http://llvm.org/apt/saucy/pool/main/l/llvm-toolchain-3.4/clang-3.4_3.4~+-1~exp1_amd64.deb' clang-3.4_3.4~+-1~exp1_amd64.deb 12571468 sha256:7a68e24fe6040fa4e5ef6a54a7c7406c04b1f7ba2bfaa5c92eee1c39adfb36b6
```